# Cube on Cube collision detection algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to check if 2 arbitrarily sized cubes collide with each other. The sides of the cubes are not necessarily all equal in length (a box is possible). Given these constraints, how could I efficiently check if they collide? (each box has 24 verticies) Thanks

They are axis alligned

Comment: Is the collision space two-dimensional or three-dimensional?  If you don't mind the collision not being exact, you can estimate the boundaries of the cube by just using some arbitrary distance from the center of the cube as the outer boundary.

Comment: Would that result in spherical, or non-box collision detection?

Comment: What kind of box has 24 vertices? A cube (or any rectangular prism, for that matter) has 8 vertices.

Comment: Because i'm not using indicies so theres overlap, I'm going to be fixing this soon,

Comment: Also, are these boxes axis-aligned?

Comment: *What kind of box has 24 vertices?* In 3D graphics you build a box from 4 quads, which gives 24 vertices. You don't want to use just 8, as the normals for every quad have to be different.

Comment: @Landel saying "in 3D graphics" is a bit of an over-generalization. I guess I wouldn't normally refer to that as a box with 24 vertices, but a box with 8 vertices, each of which has 3 normals. (And actually, if you aren't dealing with curved surfaces, you'd probably just store one normal per face, not one per vertex per face.)

Comment: If by "24 vertices" he means that he instantiates each vertex separately for every face that it participates in... then the fact that there are 24 instances of them is irrelevant. You only need the 8 abstract vertices for the intersection test. As @Laurence's answer shows.

Comment: if all its sides are not necessarily equal is not necessarily a cube

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since both boxes are axis-aligned you can just compare their extents:

```
  return (a.max_x() >= b.min_x() and a.min_x() <= b.max_x())
     and (a.max_y() >= b.min_y() and a.min_y() <= b.max_y())
     and (a.max_z() >= b.min_z() and a.min_z() <= b.max_z())
```

Comment: Would Min and Max are literally finding the minimum and maximum, is it that simple? Ex, iterating through all verticies and if v.x < minX then minX = v.x sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, though you only have to do the iteration if only b is axis aligned. Since both are axis aligned it's even simpler. See the last bit I just added.

Comment: Downvoted. This is not very helpful for collision detection. This is a boolean query. It does not find the intersection point, or work with moving objects. This approach will only work under very special circumstances.

Comment: @Mads: the "special circumstances" it works under were specified in the question.

Comment: Nor does it work on triangles.  Or render 4-dimensional meshes.  Or butter my popcorn.  Boo.

Comment: @Mads: This is not very helpful for responding to Laurence's answer. This doesn't take into account the question's requirements. It does not help improve the answer, or offer constructive criticism. This type of comment will only work under very special circumstances.

Comment: Fine, I removed the downvote, but I still think the question leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

For a boolean query, use Laurence's answer. It can also be made to work with moving boxes, but then you have to use a binary search to find the intersection point, or the time interval.

### Solving the parametric time for intersection on an axis

Another solution if you want movable boxes is to find the parametric time where the intersection happens on each axis separately, with respect to the traveling direction. Let's call the boxes A and B, their extreme points for Min and Max. You only need one direction, because you can subtract A's direction from B's direction and be left with one vector. So you can consider B to be moving and A to be stationary. Let's call the direction D. Solving for t gives:

(for the start of the intersection along D)
Bmax + tEnter*D = Amin

tEnter*D = Amin - Bmax
tEnter = (Amin - Bmax) / D

(for the end of the intersection along D; the back side of A)
Bmin + tLeave*D = Amax

tLeave*D = Amax - Bmin
tLeave = (Amax - Bmin) / D

Do this check on each axis, and if they all overlap, you have an intersection. If the denominator is zero, you have an infinite overlap or no overlap on that axis. If tEnter is greater than 1 or tLeave is less than zero, then the overlap is further away than the direction lengths, or in the wrong direction.

```
bool IntersectAxis(float min1, float max1, float min2, float max2,
    float diraxis, float& tEnter, float& tLeave)
{
    const float intrEps = 1e-9;

    /* Carefully check for diraxis==0 using an epsilon. */
    if( std::fabs(diraxis) < intrEps ){
        if((min1 >= max2) || (max1 <= min2)){
            /* No movement in the axis, and they don't overlap,
                hence no intersection. */
            return false;
        } else {
            /* Stationary in the axis, with overlap at t=0 to t=1 */
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        float start = (min1 - max2) / diraxis;
        float leave = (max1 - min2) / diraxis;

        /* Swap to make sure our intervals are correct */
        if(start > leave)
            std::swap(start,leave);

        if(start > tEnter)
            tEnter = start;
        if(leave < tLeave)
            tLeave = leave; 
        if(tEnter > tLeave)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Intersect(const AABB& b1, const AABB& b2, Vector3 dir, float& tEnter, float&         tLeave)
{
    tEnter = 0.0f;
    tLeave = 1.0f;

    if(IntersectAxis(b1.bmin.x, b1.bmax.x, b2.bmin.x, b2.bmax.x, dir.x, tEnter, tLeave) == false)
        return false;
    else if(IntersectAxis(b1.bmin.y, b1.bmax.y, b2.bmin.y, b2.bmax.y, dir.y, tEnter, tLeave) == false)
        return false;
    else if(IntersectAxis(b1.bmin.z, b1.bmax.z, b2.bmin.z, b2.bmax.z, dir.z, tEnter, tLeave) == false)
        return false;
    else
    return true;
}
```