# Calculating AABB (axis aligned bounding box) collision

Tags: c++, aabb

I'm supposed to check for AABB collision between two pyramids. I looked up AABB, simple enough to check. I was given the vertices for both pyramids, as well as 4 world positions.  I am supposed to calculate the AABB collision box, which I've done, and then see if they pyramids collide or not. The part that I'm confused on is what are the world coords for? 
There is 4 per pyramid, so they aren't vertices.. I can figure out whether or not they collide based on the vertices, so what are the world positions for?

Comment: Are you sure the 4 world positions aren't the corners of the AABB?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631437/cube-on-cube-collision-detection-algorithm
Or at least the title is.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the world positions would represent the vector transforms that indicate where the centre of the pyramids are in the world?

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to be writing an AABB sweep test?  That would require you to know how the two pyramids are moving (hence your extra information).