# How do I know when a cube collide with another moving cube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to create a little game as a training, but I'm blocked because I don't know how I can collide 2 moving cubes.

The game is simple, there is a red box that you can move and if this box touches a green cube, then you lost. (the green cubes are always moving)

I tried to read some documentations but it's not really easy to understand as a beginner.

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import random
from threading import Timer

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1100
screenHeight = 600

white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (50, 250, 20)

FPS = 60

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Tekken')
pygame.display.update()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 28)
class Players:
    def __init__(self, playerName, playerAttribute, cubeheight, cubewidth, missilesHeight, missilesWidth):
        self.playerName = playerName
        self.playerAttribute = playerAttribute
        self.playerLife = 100
        self.droite_x = 300
        self.droite_y = 600
        self.cubeheight = cubeheight
        self.cubewidth = cubewidth
        self.missiles = True
        self.missilesHeight = missilesHeight
        self.missilesWidth = missilesWidth
        self.missiles_droite_x = 0
        self.missiles_droite_y = round(random.randrange(50, screenHeight-50))
        self.missiles_droite_x_inverse = screenWidth-50
        self.missiles_droite_y_inverse = round(random.randrange(50, screenHeight-50))
        self.vitesse_missiles = 10

        print(self.playerName, self.playerAttribute, self.playerLife)

    def environment_un(self):
        gameExit = False
        gameOver = False

        droite_x_change = 0
        droite_y_change = 0
        missiles_droite_x_change = 0
        missiles_droite_x_change_inverse = 0

        while not gameExit:

            while gameOver:
                gameDisplay.fill(red)
                screen_text = font.render("Game Over, do you want to play again? [Q] to quit", True, white)
                gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [100, 300])
                pygame.display.update()

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                        if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                            gameOver = False
                            gameExit = True
                            break

                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        gameOver = False
                        gameExit = True
                        break

            for event in pygame.event.get(): #va chercher les events
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #Si j'appuie sur X
                    gameExit = True

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        droite_x_change = -3

                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        droite_x_change = +3

                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        droite_y_change = -3

                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        droite_y_change = +3

                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                         missiles_droite_x_change = self.vitesse_missiles
                         missiles_droite_x_change_inverse = -self.vitesse_missiles

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        droite_x_change = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        droite_x_change = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        droite_y_change = 0

                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        droite_y_change = 0


            self.missiles_droite_x_inverse += missiles_droite_x_change_inverse
            self.missiles_droite_x += missiles_droite_x_change
            self.droite_x += droite_x_change
            self.droite_y += droite_y_change

            if self.droite_y + self.cubeheight <= 0:
                self.droite_y = 0
            elif self.droite_y + self.cubeheight >= screenHeight:
                self.droite_y = screenHeight-self.cubeheight
            elif self.droite_x + self.cubewidth <= 0:
                self.droite_x = 0
            elif self.droite_x + self.cubewidth >= screenWidth:
                self.droite_x = screenWidth-self.cubewidth



            gameDisplay.fill(white)
            gameDisplay.fill(red, rect=[self.droite_x, self.droite_y, self.cubewidth, self.cubeheight])
            gameDisplay.fill(yellow, rect=[self.missiles_droite_x, self.missiles_droite_y, self.missilesWidth, self.missilesHeight])
            gameDisplay.fill(yellow, rect=[self.missiles_droite_x_inverse, self.missiles_droite_y_inverse, self.missilesWidth, self.missilesHeight])
            pygame.display.update()

            if self.missiles_droite_x + self.missilesWidth >= screenWidth:
                missiles_droite_x_change = 0
                if missiles_droite_x_change == 0:
                    self.missiles_droite_x = 0
                    self.missiles_droite_y = round(random.randrange(50, screenHeight-50))
                    missiles_droite_x_change = self.vitesse_missiles

            if self.missiles_droite_x_inverse <= 0:
                missiles_droite_x_change_inverse = 0
                if missiles_droite_x_change >= 0:
                    self.missiles_droite_x_inverse = screenWidth-50
                    self.missiles_droite_y_inverse = round(random.randrange(50, screenHeight-50))
                    missiles_droite_x_change_inverse = -12

            clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.quit()

Player_1 = Players('John', 'sometext', 50, 50, 100, 100)
Player_1.environment_un()
```

What should do I in order to detect the collision?

Comment: _tried to read some documentations_ <- which documentation exactly? Listing what you tried will help future posters to get more info on the subject

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cube on Cube collision detection algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631437/cube-on-cube-collision-detection-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not run your code at the moment as I dont have pygame installed. However, you can use the pygame.sprite.collide_rect() if you declare your objects to have in their class an pygame.sprite.Sprite-object or inherit from that class (as suggested below). The code below may note work as I can not test it but it should be close to a functioning code snippet. In the case you would like to test collision of a sprite against multiple other sprites - consider looking at pygame.sprite.Group(). I believe that something like this should work:

```
class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos_x, pos_y):   
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.original.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (pos_x, pos_y)

class Players:
    def __init__(self, playerName, playerAttribute, cubeheight, cubewidth, missilesHeight, missilesWidth):
        sprite1 = SpriteObject(1,2)
        sprite2 = SpriteObject(1,2)
        sprite1.rect.collide_rect(sprite2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a conceptual answer:

Since you are considering just cubes and if they are of the same size, two cubes will occupy the same space 'if and only if' a corner of one cube is between (inclusive) two parallel planes of another. There are many ways to do this in practice.

I would check if between by evaluating an inward normal vector of cube 1 dotted with a vector to a corner (of cube 2) from any corner (of cube 1) . Do so for both parallel sides. If both are positive, its inside.

It's slightly more complicated for different shapes and varying sizes.

Comment: Yeah it's different size.

Comment: Checks for a line between two corners crossing in the second cube and complete enclosure will satisfy the other remaining conflict possibilities.  Enclosure can be neglected if the ratio between fps and relative speed is sufficiently low.  I would sample the line between two corners for the check.

Answer (score -1):

Use [pygame.Rect()](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) to keep cube position and size - and then you can use [pygame.Rect.colliderect()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check collision between two cubes.

```
cube1 = pygame.Rect((x1, y1), (width, height)) 
cube2 = pygame.Rect((x2, y2), (width, height)) 

if cube1.colliderect(cube2):
     print("Collision !")
```

PyGame has other usefull classes -  [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [pygame.sprite.Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) - which use `Rect` and `collision detection` functions.

Comment: there is a difference between cube and rect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension

Comment: @LittleByBlue OP calls it `cube` but his object is 2D rectangle - see his code.

Comment: Ok, sorry, missed that.